# How to combine partial JSON results into one object/variable?

Tags: json, perl, duplicates

Having an application that returns partial JSON responses, how can I combine objects/variables into one?

---

I am using

```
$json = JSON->new->utf8->decode($response->content);
```

to convert response into object/variable, but that is for each single one.

---

Now I need it to combine several partial responses into one.

How to do that and how to deal with possible duplicates items to avoid overwriting?

---

***UPDATE:***

*To better understand the above issue see sample response below.*

*Every partial response has same structure, but different data in* `'Groups'` *,* `'Message'` *and* `'Data'` *sections. The last response comes with* `'Finished' = true`*.*

```
$VAR1 = {
  'answer' => {
    'Error' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' ),
    'Id' => 12345,
    'Finished' => $VAR1->{'answer'}{'Error'},
    'Groups' => [
      {
        'Code' => 'ABC',
        'RegNum' => 123,
        'Name' => 'John Doe'
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    'Message' => undef,
    'Data' => [
      {
        'Column1' => 'c1',
        'Column2' => 'c2'
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: [Hash::Merge](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Hash-Merge-0.12/Merge.pm)?

Comment: If you really have a partial JSON reply, just wait for the rest. If your JSON is complete, but represent merely a portion of your data structure, then this has nothing to do with JSON, and you haven't provided any information at all about your problem. We would need to know more about your data structure to know how to merge it.

Comment: @ikegami - I have updated the question with example that should clarify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge hashes by [Hash::Merge](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Hash-Merge-0.12/Merge.pm)

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing to do with JSON. You want to merge two data structures. From the little you said, there are three arrays to merge. You didn't specify how, so maybe you simply want to append the elements of the new response to the elements of the original response.

```
for (qw( Groups Message Data )) {
   push @{ $orig->{answer}{$_} }, @{ $new->{answer}{$_} }
      if $new->{answer}{$_};
}
```